# "root@host.domain.com" e-mails

Tags: email, root

I constantly receive e-mails from my "root@host.domain.com" and it is flooding my gmail inbox with 8-10 e-mails a day. Could I know what is the convention or common practice that most people use to handle such e-mails?

Do they set-up another e-mail account just for receiving these e-mails? Like maybe "webmaster@domain.com" or is there a common e-mail name that people create just for these e-mails? (like maybe junk@domain.com?)

Because I am quite sure that no one really reads these e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a GMail filter that labels them and archives them. They can be useful for digging back through in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Don't configure your servers to send unnecessary email.

Answer (score 0):

I usually receive from my webserver. What I have done is.. A filter that push the mail to a special label and mark it as read.  When I have time, I just stop by there and read it.